# Is there a way to make some widgets visible based on a dropdown selection on Dart / Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

First of all, I am relatively new on programming and specially on Dart/Flutter, so any tip on any part of the code would be deeply appreciated.

My objective with this code is to create a page with a dropdown menu (named *LabListDropdownMenu* in the code) that includes the names of some cities, then, based on the selected city, the *ListView* should only show the widgets (named *LabInfoWidget* in the code) of the labs that belong in that city. In order to do that, i'm trying to change the visibility of the *LabInfoWidget* by using booleans in order to accomplish that.

The problem: I select the items in the DropdownMenu and it changes the booleans values correctly, but it doesn't seem to alter the widgets visibility. I searched in many places but I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong. Does anyone know if am I missing something here?

Thank you for your help!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:assistente_am/widgets/widgets.dart';
import 'package:maps_launcher/maps_launcher.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class LabList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LabListState createState() => _LabListState();
}

class _LabListState extends State<LabList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Assistente(
      appBarTitle: 'Laboratory List',
      menu: LabListBody(),
    );
  }
}

Map _cityBool = {
  'City 1': isCityOne,
  'City 2': isCityTwo,
  'City 3': isCityThree,
};

var _cities = [
  'City 1',
  'City 2',
  'City 3',
];

bool isCityOne = false;
bool isCityTwo = false;
bool isCityThree = false;

class LabListBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LabListBodyState createState() => _LabListBodyState();
}

class _LabListBodyState extends State<LabListBody> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: backgroundGradient(),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Center(
            child: DecoratedBox(
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 65.0),
                child: LabListDropdownMenu(),
              ),
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(
                        width: 1.0,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                        color: Colors.cyan),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          LabInfoWidget(
            title: 'Lab 1',
            address: 'Address 1',
            schedule:
                'Monday to Friday: 09h00 - 18h00\nWeekends: Closed',
            information: 'Only by car',
            contact: ['1111111111'],
            visibilityState: isCityOne,
          ),
          LabInfoWidget(
            title: 'Lab 2',
            address: 'Address 2',
            schedule:
                'Monday to Thursday: 08h00 - 12h00\nWeekends: 12h00 - 18h00',
            information: 'Schedule by phone required',
            contact: ['2222222222'],
            visibilityState: isCityTwo
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LabInfoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  LabInfoWidget(
      {this.title,
      this.address,
      this.schedule,
      this.information,
      this.contact,
      this.visibilityState});

  final String title;
  final String address;
  final String schedule;
  final String information;
  final List contact;
  final bool visibilityState;
  @override
  _LabInfoWidgetState createState() => _LabInfoWidgetState();
}

class _LabInfoWidgetState extends State<LabInfoWidget> {
  Padding textBox(String text, FontWeight fontWeight, double fontSize) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 0.0),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: fontWeight, fontSize: fontSize),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Visibility(
      visible: widget.visibilityState,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 10.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 220),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.blue),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            widget.title,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 8,
                          ),
                          Table(
                            columnWidths: {
                              1: FractionColumnWidth(0.7),
                              2: FractionColumnWidth(1)
                            },
                            children: [
                              TableRow(children: [
                                textBox('Schedule', FontWeight.bold, 14),
                                textBox(widget.schedule, FontWeight.normal, 14)
                              ]),
                              TableRow(children: [
                                textBox('Info', FontWeight.bold, 14),
                                textBox(
                                    widget.information, FontWeight.normal, 14)
                              ]),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 60,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              int call = widget.contact[0];
                              launch(('tel://$call'));
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.call,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              MapsLauncher.launchQuery(widget.address);
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.gps_fixed_sharp,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Menu Dropdown
class LabListDropdownMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LabListDropdownMenuState createState() => _LabListDropdownMenuState();
}

class _LabListDropdownMenuState extends State<LabListDropdownMenu> {
  var _currentItemSelected;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      hint: Text(
        'Choose the desired city',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      items: _cities.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: dropDownStringItem,
          child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
        setState(() {
          this._currentItemSelected = newValueSelected;
          _cityBool.forEach((key, value) => value = false);
          _cityBool[newValueSelected] = true;
          print("$newValueSelected set to true");
        });
      },
      value: _currentItemSelected,
      dropdownColor: Colors.blue,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are calling setState((){}) method on the onChanged handler of DropdownButton, but this only rebuilds LabListDropdownMenu widget, so LabListBody is never being rebuilt.

To solve this you may pass a callback function to LabListDropdownMenu. This way, when the onChanged method gets fired, you can also invoke this callback to rebuild LabListBody.

It's kind of difficult to express it in words, so I've edited your code a little bit. I've also made some other minor edits to it:

```
Map _cityBool = new Map();

var _cities = [
  'City 1',
  'City 2',
  'City 3',
];

class LabList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LabListState createState() => _LabListState();
}

class _LabListState extends State<LabList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Laboratory List')
      ),
      body: LabListBody(),
    );
  }
}

class LabListBody extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LabListBodyState createState() => _LabListBodyState();
}

class _LabListBodyState extends State<LabListBody> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    _cities.forEach((element) {
      _cityBool[element] = false;
    });
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("city bools array: ${_cityBool[_cities[0]]}, ${_cityBool[_cities[1]]}, ${_cityBool[_cities[2]]}");
    return Container(
      //decoration: backgroundGradient(),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 15,
          ),
          Center(
            child: DecoratedBox(
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 65.0),
                child: LabListDropdownMenu(onDropdownChange: (String value) {
                    print("onDropdownChange $value");
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
              ),
              decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(
                        width: 1.0,
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                        color: Colors.cyan),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 15),
          LabInfoWidget(
            title: 'Lab 1',
            address: 'Address 1',
            schedule:
            'Monday to Friday: 09h00 - 18h00\nWeekends: Closed',
            information: 'Only by car',
            contact: ['1111111111'],
            visibilityState: _cityBool[_cities[0]],
          ),
          LabInfoWidget(
              title: 'Lab 2',
              address: 'Address 2',
              schedule:
              'Monday to Thursday: 08h00 - 12h00\nWeekends: 12h00 - 18h00',
              information: 'Schedule by phone required',
              contact: ['2222222222'],
              visibilityState: _cityBool[_cities[1]]
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LabInfoWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  LabInfoWidget(
      {this.title,
        this.address,
        this.schedule,
        this.information,
        this.contact,
        this.visibilityState});

  final String title;
  final String address;
  final String schedule;
  final String information;
  final List contact;
  final bool visibilityState;
  @override
  _LabInfoWidgetState createState() => _LabInfoWidgetState();
}

class _LabInfoWidgetState extends State<LabInfoWidget> {
  Padding textBox(String text, FontWeight fontWeight, double fontSize) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 0.0),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: fontWeight, fontSize: fontSize),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Visibility(
      visible: widget.visibilityState,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0, horizontal: 10.0),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 400, maxHeight: 220),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Colors.blue),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            widget.title,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 20,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 8,
                          ),
                          Table(
                            columnWidths: {
                              1: FractionColumnWidth(0.7),
                              2: FractionColumnWidth(1)
                            },
                            children: [
                              TableRow(children: [
                                textBox('Schedule', FontWeight.bold, 14),
                                textBox(widget.schedule, FontWeight.normal, 14)
                              ]),
                              TableRow(children: [
                                textBox('Info', FontWeight.bold, 14),
                                textBox(
                                    widget.information, FontWeight.normal, 14)
                              ]),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 60,
                    child: Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.blue,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              int call = widget.contact[0];
                              //launch(('tel://$call'));
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.call,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              //MapsLauncher.launchQuery(widget.address);
                            },
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.gps_fixed_sharp,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Menu Dropdown
class LabListDropdownMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function onDropdownChange;
  LabListDropdownMenu({
    @required this.onDropdownChange,
  });
  @override
  _LabListDropdownMenuState createState() => _LabListDropdownMenuState();
}

class _LabListDropdownMenuState extends State<LabListDropdownMenu> {
  var _currentItemSelected;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      hint: Text(
        'Choose the desired city',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      items: _cities.map((String dropDownStringItem) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: dropDownStringItem,
          child: Text(dropDownStringItem),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (String newValueSelected) {
        setState(() {
          this._currentItemSelected = newValueSelected;
          _cityBool.forEach((key, value) {
            _cityBool.update(key, (value) => false);
          });
          //_cityBool.forEach((key, value) => value = false);
          _cityBool[newValueSelected] = true;
        });
        widget.onDropdownChange(newValueSelected);
      },
      value: _currentItemSelected,
      dropdownColor: Colors.blue,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_drop_down,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```